# Empty generated qrc files on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, ninja

I am trying to build a simple QML project on Raspberry Pi but I keep running into this

```
[6/18 29.9/sec] Running rcc for resource qmake_untitled2
FAILED: .rcc/qrc_qmake_untitled2.cpp /home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug/.rcc/qrc_qmake_untitled2.cpp 
cd /home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug && /opt/Qt/6.6/./libexec/rcc --output /home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug/.rcc/qrc_qmake_untitled2.cpp --name qmake_untitled2 /home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug/.rcc/qmake_untitled2.qrc
RCC Parse Error: '/home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug/.rcc/qmake_untitled2.qrc' Line: 1 Column: 0 [Premature end of document.]
[7/18 34.8/sec] Running rcc for resource appuntitled2_raw_qml_0
FAILED: .rcc/qrc_appuntitled2_raw_qml_0.cpp /home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug/.rcc/qrc_appuntitled2_raw_qml_0.cpp 
cd /home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug && /opt/Qt/6.6/./libexec/rcc --output /home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug/.rcc/qrc_appuntitled2_raw_qml_0.cpp --name appuntitled2_raw_qml_0 /home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug/.rcc/appuntitled2_raw_qml_0.qrc
RCC Parse Error: '/home/khangnguyen2003/build-untitled2-Desktop-Debug/.rcc/appuntitled2_raw_qml_0.qrc' Line: 1 Column: 0 [Premature end of document.]
[8/18 33.5/sec] Running moc --collect-json for target appuntitled2
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

problem. This problem is due to the generated `appuntitled2_raw_qml_0.qrc` and `qmake_untitled2.qrc` files being empty after generated.During the installation process for Qt6 and its submodule, which I followed [this](https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-66-raspberry-pi-raspberry-pi-os) and [this](https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-66-sub-modules) guides, I occurred the same error where running `qt-configure-modules` in the submodule folders generates empty qrc files. I managed to circumvent that issue by doing the same procedure in my Linux desktop, which actually generates populated qrc files, then modify the content in those qrc files and copy it over to my Raspberry Pi.

I would like to know what is the potential cause for this issue. Thank you very much